# VueJS Race condition during setup methods

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pinia

I have been experimenting with VueJS and have run into a pretty frustrating issue dealing with promises and component state. I come from React so I could be going about this incorrectly. I have been unable to work my around around this particular issue.

I am using Pinia to store the state and I am trying to update a `CharacterSummary` object within the Home component's setup method. However I am hitting a race condition with a request that needs to happen in the top level App component.

My question is what is the proper way to handle an "initial loading" scenario using global state in vue?

Here is the store definition. All api calls are async and generated using the `openapi-typescript-codegen` package

```js
import {
  Api,
  type WowCharacterSummary,
  type WowPlayerCharacter,
} from "@/client";
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

interface PlayerStore {
  playerCharacters: WowPlayerCharacter[];
  currentSelectedCharacter: string;
  characterSummary: WowCharacterSummary | null;
}

export const usePlayerStore = defineStore("player", {
  state: (): PlayerStore => ({
    playerCharacters: [],
    currentSelectedCharacter: "",
    characterSummary: null,
  }),
  actions: {
    async loadInitial() {
      const api = new Api();

      const access_token = "";

      if (access_token) {
        const playerCharactersResponse =
          await api.default.getPlayerUserInfoPlayerInfoGet(access_token);

        this.playerCharacters = playerCharactersResponse;
      }
    },
    async loadCharacterInfo(charName: string) {
      const api = new Api();

      const charResult =
        await api.default.getCharacterSummaryCharacterNameSummaryGet(charName);

      this.characterSummary = charResult;
    },
  },
});
```

In `App.vue` I am calling the `loadInitial` method to populate the `playerCharacters` state. It should be noted that if I await this call, the whole app stops loading. Adding `<Suspense></Suspense>` at the top level doesn't seem to help.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from "vue-router";
import BaseLine from "./components/layouts/BaseLine.vue";
import { usePlayerStore } from "./stores/player";

const { loadInitial } = usePlayerStore();
loadInitial();
</script>

<template>
  <BaseLine>
    <Suspense>
      <RouterView />
    </Suspense>
  </BaseLine>
</template>
```

And in `HomeView.vue` I am trying to use the values within `playerCharacters` to call a second endpoint and load more information.

```js
<template>
  <main>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="c in playerCharacters" :key="c.name">
        <p>{{ c.name }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
      <h1>{{ characterSummary?.name }}</h1>
      <h2>{{ characterSummary?.level }}</h2>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { usePlayerStore } from "@/stores/player";
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";

export default {
  setup: async () => {
    const playerStore = usePlayerStore();
    const { characterSummary, playerCharacters } = storeToRefs(playerStore);

    if (playerCharacters.value.length > 0) {
      await playerStore.loadCharacterInfo(playerCharacters.value[0].name);
    }

    return { playerCharacters, characterSummary };
  },
};
</script>
```

The list of character names loads correctly every time but the `charcaterSummary` will only display if I have a break point in the right place, so it is very clearly a race condition issue.

Any help would be appreciated, I just need some help seeing what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `It should be noted that if I await this call, the whole app stops loading.` What do you mean stops loading? You mean it doesn't render until the promise is resolved?

Comment: It's a mistake to rely on playerCharacters.value in setup because it's not guaranteed to exist. Since it belong to initial data, you can postpone the rendering of the whole app until loadInitial is complete

Comment: @EstusFlask Hey. BTW my problem last night was because of the laravel-vite-plugin. It prevents Vite's default behavior of generating an index.html file. Thanks again.

Comment: @bassxzero Just shows a white screen so I would assume so? considering it's a promise<void> I'm not sure what I am doing wrong there

Comment: @EstusFlask I had thought that's what would happen when I would await the loadInitial call, but the page would just be white

Comment: When you use async comp (await in setup), you should have another <suspense> in a parent. If App is currently root comp, it should be wrapped with another comp

Comment: Got it! Okay, I moved the call up to the main file and wrapped the mount call around a then. Thanks heaps @EstusFlask I didn't realise async HAD to wrapped in suspense, if you want to make this an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loadInitial` isn't waited during initial render, this results in race condition.

[Asynchronous components with `async` setup](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#async-setup) should be wrapped with `<suspense>`, they cannot work otherwise because setup function returns promise object instead of component instance and needs to be treated in a special way by Vue renderer.

In case top-level component is asynchronous, it needs to be wrapped with another component that contains `<suspense>`.

Alternatively, the application can be initialized prior to rendering:

```
await loadInitial();
app.mount(...);
```